# How to handle a database operation that takes 15 minutes to complete in a Spring MVC web application?

Tags: database, spring-mvc, parallel-processing, httprequest, informix

My task is to create a report for each of 4 hierarchical dependent entities in the database. Let's name those entities A, B, C and D. In order to generate a report for A, I need to have all the reports for B generated. To generate a report for B, all C level reports must be generated first. The same goes for C; I need all D level reports generated.

I am using Spring MVC in my application. Generating a report for the lowest level entity (D) takes about 3 seconds and can be handled in a single HTTP request. For a "C" level entity it usually takes 10-12 seconds. At "B" level it starts getting pretty intensive: 3-4 minutes for a report. "A" level reports take 15 minutes to complete.

Generating a D level report is done by calling a stored procedure on a database. The reports for all the other higher levels are done using java iterative loops which generate all dependent reports up to level D (ultimately calling the same stored procedure on the database).

What's the best way to cut time on this intensive operation? I am using Spring MVC, JPA/Hibernate and Bitronix Transaction Manager [JTA] (each stored procedure call for generating a level D report opens a read-only transaction).

Should I use threading to run lower level report generation in parallel?

Is it normal for an operation to take such a long time or am I doing something terribly wrong?

How does one handle such an intensive operation so that the user should get the requested data without having to wait 15 minutes for a HTTP request to complete?

**EDIT:**

After some tweaking I implemented a parallel algorithm using Java Futures and Spring's @Async mechanism. An A level report now takes 3 minutes to complete. I am curious whether the parallelization can be further improved. I don't really know if the underlying DBMS (IBM Informix 11.5 in my case) is locking rows on read so that can be a further issue I could resolve. Would setting the Isolation level of a transaction help in this case?

Comment: Hi, Are you saying you always request A,B,C and D? In other words, you never request just A or just B, etc. Again, are you required to construct all four "reports"? The output of your process is always all four "reports"? Is that correct? Is all of the data you need for all 4 reports contained in the database? Is that correct?

Comment: I can choose in my application what level of report i need to generate. For level A it takes a long time because it has to build all reports for lower level entities due to the fact that the output of a level A report is based on all of these lower level reports. Yes all the data is in the database but I can only extract level D data from it through a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Have you profiled the process? Do you know what is causing the bottleneck? What if it's not your java process but transporting data in and out of the database?Transporting the data across the network? If you process all the reports as stored procedures you eliminate that type of overhead. My  advice is determine the bottleneck first. You need to know what to optimize. Typically stored procedures process the fastest. But you have not posted any of the details. Thus, just a wild guess :) Move all the processing in to the database.